# How to remove the confirm dialog in iframe from parent page?

Tags: javascript

I have two html pages. say parent.html and child.html.
child.html have a confirm dialog

```
  confirm("Are you sure?");
```

How to override the confirm dialog from parent.html?

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="iFrame" src="child.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go inside the iframe context and overwrite the native confirm function

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
frames[0].contentWindow.confirm = null;
```

NOTE: the function will still alive in the parent scope.

I think it's not the best solution the shoutdown/overwriting of native functions; the best thing to do is to stop the events that invoke the confirm function in child frame.